# Mysql table doesnt exist, but it does

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird error, using MyPhpAdmin, I added a row, and the script it generates is:

```
INSERT INTO 'Users'.'User_Accounts'('Account_ID', 'UserName',
'Email', 'PhoneNumber', 'Password') VALUES (NULL, 'fdsfsadf',
'dfsadf', 'sdfads', 'fsdfasdfsd');
```

That works, however when I use PHP PDO to insert it gives this error:

```
Table 'Users.User_Acounts' doesn't exist
```

uhhhh yes it does...

The PHP code:

```
$hostname = "127.0.0.1";
$port     = "3306";
$database = "Users";
$username = "AccountControl";
$password = "w67hLAanWESGNJMC";

echo ">>";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; port=$port; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
echo ">>";
$UserName = "KiteDev";
$Email = "johndoveail.com";
$PhoneNumber = "66666";
$Password = "dfsgetagfdasg";

// Create the query
$query = "INSERT INTO User_Acounts (UserName, Email, Phon2eNumber, Password) VALUES (:name, :email, :phone, :pass )";

// Prepare statement with $stmt variable
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
echo ">>";
// Bind parameters, (you can also remove the PDO::PARAM_INT)
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $UserName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':phone', $PhoneNumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $Password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Execute the query once you're done binding all the params
$stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
echo ">>";
```

Any ideas as to what's causing this?

Comment: use `User_Accounts` instead of `User_Acounts`. spelling is incorrect in `$query = "INSERT INTO User_Acounts `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled `User_Accounts`. The table you created is `User.User_Accounts` but the table that doesn't exist is `User.User_Acounts`.

Comment: Augh. This is proof I need a break. Such a dumb mistake. Thanks

Comment: Ha, it happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote accounts with one c

```
Table 'Users.User_Acounts' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

The Table Name is `User_Accounts`. In your php code, it is misspelled as `User_Acounts`

Correct it as

> $query = "INSERT INTO User_Accounts (UserName, Email, Phon2eNumber,
>   Password) VALUES (:name, :email, :phone, :pass )";